# Using VB DLL in TWO windows project at the same machine

Tags: vb.net, dll

I Have old vb windows application, we develop new .Net Application that uses the old VB DLL functions, for testing purposes I have to install the two application in one client machine,

BUT The Problem:

*When I install the new .Net and register the DLL , it works fine,*,

-- But the old VB application Stops...

*If i register the DLL again and run the VB application , it works fine...*

-- But the new .Net Application not works,,

**After Registering the DLL, the first Application I run works fine , the other NOT**

> HOW COULD I RUN THE TWO APPLICATION AT
>   THE SAME TIME USING THE SAME DLL???

THaNKS,,,    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET you have more ways to use a DLL than registering it. I suggest putting it on your programs working folder and referencing it directly. Then the two should run independent from eachother.

Other than that, no, you can't run both versions at once. Welcome to DLL Hell :).

Comment: Thanks... Actually I Include the DLL in the .Net Application, when I Install the application in client machine , it appears in installation directory , but when i run the NEW application the old stops,,, it seems that both DLL registered in REGISTRY with the same class GUID ,,, and one application can use that class...                 DLL Hell :(

Comment: I'm not gonna lie and pretend I have a lot of experience with using COM+ in .NET (I heard it was "A Bad Thing"). But I was under the impression that you can use it WITHOUT registering...

Comment: You can, but it's not as simple as deploying it to the bin directory. "registration free com" is the Google search you will want, but the best documentation is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx.